# "Your Second iOS App": How do I implement a Singleton?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, singleton

I am still trying to improve ["My Second iOS App"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html), which is a tutorial provided by Apple. Here is a picture of the storyboard with added commentary of what should happen.

[image: detail of the storyboard with added commentary]

When the done button (step 3) is clicked, the actual screen should return to the main menu (3.a) while the finished BirdSightingObject should be added to the list of `BirdMasterViewController` (3.b). So I figured that I could use a Singleton, since there could be only one object added simultaniously and it makes accessing from different classes much easier.

In the tutorial a class is already given for data handeling, "`BirdSighting`", which could probably be used as a singleton. But as I have only beginner level knowledge of OOP and design patterns I don't know, if I can use this, or if I have to to write my own in reference to the existing class.

And secondly: I haven't the slightest idea how to access the `BirdMasterViewController` in the `(IBAction)done` method to finally save the object in the list.

<sup>Note: The following source code is partially provided by Apple, Inc. Refer to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CodeListings/CodeListings.html) to see a full code listing of the tutorial. No copy right infridgement is intended.</sup>

`BirdSighting.h`:

```
@interface BirdSighting : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location date:(NSDate *)date;
- (id)initWithNameOnly:(NSString *)name date:(NSDate *)date;

@end
```

`BirdSighting.m`:

```
#import "BirdSighting.h"

@implementation BirdSighting

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location date:(NSDate *)date
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _name = name;
        _location = location;
        _date = date;
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(id)initWithNameOnly:(NSString *)name date:(NSDate *)date
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _name = name;
        _date = date;
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

The `(IBAction)done` method, in `MainMenuViewController.m`:

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ReturnInput"])
    {
        AddLocationToSighting *addController = [segue sourceViewController];
        if (addController.birdSighting)
        {
            [self.dataController addBirdSightingWithSighting:addController.birdSighting];
            [[self tableView] reloadData];
        }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Summary:

- **May I transform** `BirdSighting` **into a singleton?** And if so, what is missing? (No need to code it out for me, I hope I can do it on my own if you provide a hint.)
- **How do I save the object in the** `BirdMasterViewController`**?** I have no idea how to access the noninvolved ViewController in `(IBAction)done`.

Comment: P.S.: If my question is to specific, or if I should separate the two questions, please let me know. I'm also quite new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: i guess people here dont allow to help other, whether they can help or not. Good luck @RNelke

Comment: @DipenPanchasara What we don't allow is answers that are of a low enough quality that they may be considered worthless to the asker of the question.  This site is not about wading through cruft, it's about putting quality answers and questions out where everyone can see them and learn from them.  I didn't mean to be rude down there, it's just that we expect a higher quality of post around here.

Comment: yes i agree with you @CodaFi

Comment: @DipenPanchasara We also believe in redemption.  You are free to edit and undete that post if you find that you have an answer that you think works for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> May I transform BirdSighting into a singleton?

No.

`BirdSighting` is a *model object*, not a collection, and certainly not a variable that needs to be globally accessible.  You can, however, make a singleton Bird Sighting Manager, that controls a list of bird sightings and can add, remove, or serialize them as appropriate.  Although, bear in mind that singletons create global state, which is always a bad thing.

> How do I save the object in the BirdMasterViewController?

This, again, comes back to the singleton suggested above.  I would also suggest some form of delegation between the add controller and the main list view, but I see that might be a challenge with all the intermediate view controllers.  Even a notification would work (with the new sighting in the `info` parameter).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand my mistake in thinking, I could convert `BirdSighting` into a singleton. But I haven't worked with delegates before and don't know what you mean by `info` parameter. Could you go into detail on that or link me up with a tutorial for explanation?

Comment: Don't convert the class, write a new one that controls an array of those bird sightings.  Ignore the delegation idea, it's a little hard to explain in a comment.  The notification thing is simple: When done is pressed, [broadcast a notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Make the main view controller listen and react to it.

Comment: When you see an object that can be made multiple times (there isn't just one bird sighting in the world!) the last thing you think about is a singleton.  Singletons are, in my opinion, a last resort.  Global state in an application is just stuffing that you wade through to get to actual, useful code.  That said, for simple problems, they suffice.

Comment: Of course I didn't think of the easiest solution again (array). And thank you for the link, I'll read into that. But did you mean the `main view controller`, or shouldnt rather the `BirdMasterVC` listen to the notification?

Comment: Absolutely!  I'm sure there's a better way to go about doing all this, but for now, this works.